# Getting all html form data in a multi-paged/multi-part form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, multipage, multipartform-data

I have a multi-paged forms and I need to get all the data from the forms. I know I can do this manually but I want a more dynamic approach. Yeah, if possible, please give me an answer using javascript only.

Edit...
I'm sorry if it was somewhat vague.
What I want to do is to present to the user all the data he entered, so i think this is client-side not server-side. Also, I have installed PHP now. So, if there's a PHP way, then that's also ok.

It's multi-paged because the user will jump from different web-pages because it will be very long if the user will input all the data in just one page. Hmmm... an example would be a tax-filing form. Or some kind of census. That's how long the form is and the amount of data I have to get. So, I want to know a dynamic way to do it.

I'm still not finished. Thanks to the comments below. I have tried them and some are beneficial.

Comment: What are you trying to do? get all data and post it to a php site?

Comment: yeah, that's what i wanted to do but since i do not have a wampp server right now (my internet connection is as slow as hell), i'm looking for a javascript solution...yeah I can use jquery

Comment: Also, "get all the data from the forms": what sort of data?  Do you want input name|value pairs?

Comment: i have installed PHP now so i know how to extract the data into name-value pairs, what I want to know now is how to collect them form a multi-paged form...the user has to click to a next page link and then continue to fill out the next forms

Comment: If you solved your problem, write an answer. This is a Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I have solved my problem. This is how I did it.

First, instead of using multiple pages, I used hidden divs and make it visible as the user clicks the next page and make the present form hidden.

Then, I learned that I can access all the data by using this code: 
`var value = document.forms[formname].elements[index].value;`
and put it inside a loop

and then process it all by:

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST['form1'])) {
    //do some sever-side processing and validation;
}

if (!empty($_POST['form2'])) {
    //do some sever-side processing and validation;
}

.....
?>
```

Thanks for all the help btw.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$.post("destination_site.php", $("form").serialize());
```

It selects all "form" Tags on the page it is executed and then post the serialized data to "destination_site.php"

On your script site, you can access them with `$_POST['name_of_input_element']`

If you want to access the input elements on the client site, you dont need to post them.
Use this to access all input elements of all forms of your site

```
$.each("form :input", function(index, value) { 
  // show message box of input value
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: yeah, sorry.
now, off to improving the visuals of the page. Web development is really cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery's [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) you can get every field from a form and then send it to a php script with [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: you can do that without jquery, too

Comment: how can I parse the string from the serialize method and get it one by one

Comment: with "parse" you mean "access" them? on server site with php or clientsite with js?

Comment: you can also make an ajax request without jquery( or prototype, etc.) and/or animate elements with simple javascript but what's the point in reinventing the wheel?

Comment: so you want to parse the content of the form in javascript, is that correct?

Comment: yes, because i have to show to the user all the data he inputted
i think this is client-side. but if not, then please correct me